# How to get an access token in Angular with the OAuth2 client credentials flow

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

How can I get token in code with oauth2 client credentials for my angular project? I couldn't find any examples on the net so I just get token from postman and paste it in code like this:

```
const header = new HttpHeaders({
  'Authorization': 'Bearer bb4229ba-8ece-4cd4-a1cf-720b55d5fc27',
  'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
});
```

Comment: I personally recommend to not implement oauth by yourself and use a lib instead. I can ecommend the lib of Manfred Steyer https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc

Comment: You should avoid the `client credentials` flow for your Angular app. It should be used between highly trusted server to server applications . Instead go with recommended oauth `authorization code` flow for obtaining the token.

Comment: I agree with @harry. On top of what he said, you can use PKCE flow which is an extension to the authorization_code flow to prevent the Middle-In-The-Man attack

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-client-credentials-flow) by Auth0 (disclaimer: I do not work at Auth0). It shows how to use the client credentials OAuth flow in different languages including JS.

Here's how you would do it in Node.js

```
var axios = require("axios").default;

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token',
  headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  data: new URLSearchParams({
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    audience: 'YOUR_API_IDENTIFIER'
  })
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

### WARNING

Note the comments left on your question: avoid using client credentials. That's because it's a flow that is not safe to use with public clients e.g. mobile apps or SPA. CC should be used in machine-to-machine calls only.

Note also you should avoid implementing OAuth client functionality on your own. There are lots of libraries that do the heavy work for you.